# Spark Kafka Task not serializable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have run to a wall on getting around a Task not serializable when trying to break out a spark application into classes and use Try also.

The Code pulls from S3 for schema, does a streaming read from Kafka (which the topic is avro format with schema reg).

I have tried using the class and not using the class... but in both cases I'm getting a serz error relating to a closure.. which I guess something is being pulled in when it is trying to serz. This error haunts me always.. such a huge pain to get around. If someone could shed some light on how I can avoid this issue that would be awesome. These Java classes seem to have more issues than they are worth sometimes.

```
   import java.util.Properties
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.{AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig, KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig}
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, from_json}
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

case class DeserializedFromKafkaRecord(value: String)

class sparkS3() extends Serializable {
  def readpeopleSchemaDF(spark: SparkSession, topicSchemaLocation: String): scala.util.Try[StructType] = {
    val read: scala.util.Try[StructType] = Try(
      spark
        .read
        .option("header", "true")
        .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
        .load(topicSchemaLocation)
        .schema
    )
    read
  }

  def writeTopicDF(peopleDFstream: DataFrame,
                   peopleDFstreamCheckpoint: String,
                   peopleDFstreamLocation: String): scala.util.Try[StreamingQuery] = {
    val write: scala.util.Try[StreamingQuery] = Try(
      peopleDFstream
        .writeStream
        .option("checkpointLocation", peopleDFstreamCheckpoint)
        .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
        .option("path", peopleDFstreamLocation)
        .start()
    )
    write
  }
}

class sparkKafka() extends Serializable {

  def readpeopleTopicDF(spark: SparkSession, topicSchema: StructType): scala.util.Try[DataFrame] = {
    val brokers = "URL:9092"
    val schemaRegistryURL = "URL:8081"
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
      "key.deserializer" -> "KafkaAvroDeserializer",
      "value.deserializer" -> "KafkaAvroDeserializer",
      "group.id" -> "structured-kafka",
      //"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "failOnDataLoss" -> "false",
      "schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryURL
    )
    var kafkaTopic = "people"

    object avroDeserializerWrapper {
      val props = new Properties()
      props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURL)
      props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true")
      val vProps = new kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties(props)
      val deser = new KafkaAvroDecoder(vProps)
      val avro_schema = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL).getLatestVersion(kafkaTopic + "-value")
      val messageSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avro_schema.getSchema)
    }
    import spark.implicits._

    val read: scala.util.Try[DataFrame] = Try(
      {
        val peopleStringDF = {
          spark
            .readStream
            .format("kafka")
            .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
            .options(kafkaParams)
            .load()
            .map(x => {
              DeserializedFromKafkaRecord(avroDeserializerWrapper.deser.fromBytes(
                x
                  .getAs[Array[Byte]]("value"), avroDeserializerWrapper.messageSchema)
                .asInstanceOf[GenericData.Record].toString)
            })
        }
        val peopleJsonDF = {
          peopleStringDF
            .select(
              from_json(col("value")
                .cast("string"), topicSchema)
                .alias("people"))
        }
        peopleJsonDF.select("people.*")
      })
    read
  }
}


object peopleDataLakePreprocStage1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("peoplePreProcConsumerStage1")
      .getOrCreate()

    val topicSchemaLocation = "URL"
    val topicDFstreamCheckpoint = "URL"
    val topicDFstreamLocation = "URL"

    val sparkKafka = new sparkKafka()
    val sparkS3 = new sparkS3()


    sparkS3.readpepleSchemaDF(spark, topicSchemaLocation) match {
      case Success(topicSchema) => {
        sparkKafka.readpeopletTopicDF(spark, topicSchema) match {
          case Success(df) => {
            sparkS3.writeTopicDF(df, topicDFstreamCheckpoint, topicDFstreamLocation) match {
              case Success(query) => {
                query.awaitTermination()
              }
              case Failure(f) => println(f)
            }
          }
          case Failure(f) => println(f)
        }
      }
      case Failure(f) => println(f)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: s3a://... when compacting batch 9 (compactInterval: 10)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.compact(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.add(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
18/08/10 13:04:07 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 2876ded4-f223-40c4-8634-0c8feec94bf6, runId = 9b9a1347-7a80-4295-bb6e-ff2de18eeaf4] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: s3a://..../_spark_metadata/0 doesn't exist when compacting batch 9 (compactInterval: 10)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.compact(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.add(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution was one of two (or both) things.. extend serialzation on the class , separate files in the same namespace.  I have updated the code above to reflect

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab. In class **sparkS3** you are using 'var' to define those values - did you mean 'val'?

Comment: I try to use var when I'm testing the code, and then go back and replace with val as needed. I'm happy to try that but I don't think that would have much of an effect.

Comment: val and var are handled significantly differently.  The immutability of data is one of the principles that lets Spark do what it does.  If it also had to handle input data changing while the executors are processing everything would fall apart. :)  Like I said though, just a thought!

Comment: ok changed all the vars to vals I also updated the code so it compiles. Still a serialization error. I'll update the code and error above.

Comment: so I separated the classes into separate files, and make them serializable. which may have resolved those errors. I have a new error about task and metadata.. I will update the code.